# Failing to catch Errno::ECONNRESET in Ruby code

Tags: ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, fog

In my Rails 3.1 project, deployed to Heroku, I have a rake task that generates a few hundred thousand small PNGs based on records in the database and uploads the results to S3 using [fog](http://fog.io/), one file at a time. (Before I was using heroku, the task saved the files locally and everything worked fine.) When I run the task using `heroku run:detached`, it runs for a while, and uploads a bunch of files, but eventually fails with `Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)`. What's weird about this is that I've modified the script to catch and retry that exception like so:

```rb
file_exists = false
retry_count = 10
begin
  file_exists = directory.files.head(filekey)
rescue Errno::ECONNRESET => e
  if retry_count > 0 then
    logger.warning("Connection reset: #{e.inspect}")
    retry_count -= 1
    sleep(1)
    retry
  else
    raise
  end
end
```

According to the stack trace, `file_exists = directory.files.head(filekey)` is the line of my code that leads to the exception, so I feel like I'm missing something about Ruby exception handling. I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong, since I'm not 100% sure if this is a problem with my begin/rescue block, the way fog handles network errors, or what.

Here's the complete stack trace:

```
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/buffering.rb:36:in `sysread'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/buffering.rb:36:in `fill_rbuff'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/buffering.rb:68:in `read'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/excon-0.16.7/lib/excon/socket.rb:121:in `read'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/excon-0.16.7/lib/excon/socket.rb:120:in `read'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/excon-0.16.7/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:79:in `read'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/excon-0.16.7/lib/excon/response.rb:21:in `parse'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/excon-0.16.7/lib/excon/connection.rb:275:in `request_kernel'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/excon-0.16.7/lib/excon/connection.rb:103:in `request'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:20:in `request'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog/aws/storage.rb:392:in `request'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog/aws/requests/storage/head_object.rb:53:in `head_object'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog/aws/models/storage/files.rb:98:in `head'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/lib/tasks/assets.rake:45
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/lib/tasks/assets.rake:37:in `each'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/lib/tasks/assets.rake:37
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `find_each'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `each'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `find_each'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:69:in `find_in_batches'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:20:in `find_each'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/lib/tasks/assets.rake:35
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/ruby-1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:23:in `load'
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:23
Nov 07 12:08:01 ... app/run.1:  Tasks: TOP => ...:make_outlines
Nov 07 12:08:02 ... heroku/run.1:  Process exited with status 1
Nov 07 12:08:02 ... heroku/run.1:  State changed from up to complete
```

Comment: you need to log retry_count to be sure it never retried 10 times, you might be surprised connection was out for over 10 seconds

Comment: This didn't end up being the problem, but it's true. The ideal solution would probably involve a more sophisticated wait-and-retry cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps try like this:

```
begin
  ...
rescue Errno::ECONNRESET => e
  ...
rescue => e
  ...
end
```

Comment: Good idea. Trying, will report back.

Comment: Ah, of course: the exception is actually Excon::Errors::SocketError. Excon must be wrapping ECONNRESET. I kind of wish Ruby would include the exception class with the stack trace, but maybe there's a reason not to and I don't know it yet?